# Force Pixel Shader Effect to run in parallel for only 1 image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, gpu, pixel-shader

I have wpf application showing very large image with pixel shader effect (contrast adjust) on it. Perform very nice until I scale up the image (which brings great amount of pixels to be rendered).

I noticed that if I'm cropping the image to smaller parts and put them in ItemsControl, performance is boost up because GPU runs the effect in parallel on each cropped image.

Is it possible to force GPU run in parallel also for 1 image ?

I'm using DirectX 9. ( since my app should run on XP as well )

Another approach to reduce performance could be to run the effect only on the screen pixels and not entire pixels. could not found way to that either...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the shader is being applied at the display frame rate. Try drawing it with a DrawingBrush and set the RenderOptions.CachingHint to "Cache" as described in [the MSDN help documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.cachinghint%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried this (hope that's you meant). did not help. performance become worse :(
<Image.Resources>
   <VisualBrush x:Key="visualBrush"  RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"/>
</Image.Resources>

<Image.Effect>
  <shaders:ContrastAdjustEffect                                       Contrast="{Binding Contrast}" Brightness="{Binding Brightness}"
                            Input="{StaticResource visualBrush}"/>
</Image.Effect>

Comment: Any chance you can post working code I can test my end?